# Save a TcpListener in OnSaveInstanceState (Xamarin)

Tags: android, xamarin, xamarin.android, android-lifecycle

I got a Problem. I have a Xamarin Android App which opens a TcpListener. Now when I rotate the device or unlock the OnCreate Method will be called. So a new TcpListener will be created, what I don't want. Is there a solution to store a reference at OnSaveInstanceState in Bundle so, I can Access the TcpListener in the OnCreate Method?

Thank You

Answer (score 0):

If you don't want your OnCreate to be called on orientation change all you have to do is add the following line in your Activity header:

For API > 13

```
ConfigurationChanges = ConfigChanges.ScreenSize | ConfigChanges.Orientation
```

For API < 13

```
 ConfigurationChanges =  ConfigChanges.Orientation
```

For Eg:

```
[Activity(ConfigurationChanges = ConfigChanges.ScreenSize | ConfigChanges.Orientation,...)
public class MainActivity : AppCompatActivity
```

**Update**

For the changes that you need to do on orientation change, you can just use the below method to make the changes

```
  public override void OnConfigurationChanged(Configuration newConfig)
    {
        base.OnConfigurationChanged(newConfig);
        //Config changes here 
    }
```

Comment: ... but then you have to handle the whole orientation change manually, e.g. resizing of widgets and so on.

Comment: No you can just override the onConfigurationChanged will update that aswell

Comment: That's what I meant.